# Super pom and plugins

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

According to this book I am reading, in my super pom I must find the following code :

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>default-clean</id>
    <phase>clean</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>clean</goal>
    </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

While in my super pom I find no goals or anything specified, like so :

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

The only plugin which was specified is the dependency plugin. The goal was set to copy:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/hp-pc/test_maven/project/target/endorsed</outputDirectory>
          <silent>true</silent>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>javax</groupId>
              <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
              <version>7.0</version>
              <type>jar</type>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Can you explain why I find this difference and what's "copy" defined in the goal ?

Comment: *While in my super pom I find no goals or anything specified* Where exactly did you look?

Comment: I looked in my effective-pom.

Comment: Hmm. What is your Maven version? Also, the effective POM can be quite long, sure it's not hidden somewhere? :)

Comment: I am using version 2.2.1 and for the clean plugin I am sure there is nothing specified .

Comment: Maven 2.2.1 is quite old also. I'm sure the book you're reading is targeting Maven 3.

Comment: ok thanks. I checked, it was a version problem.